# Display text on top of an image

Tags: html, css, positioning, typography

At the moment I'm trying to display text on top of image and the way that I'm organising it as I have multiple images is like so

```
<div class="imageDiv">
    <img ..... class=....>
    <div class="textToBeOnTop">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Now I set the position to relative on textToBeOnTop div as I want to centre it and animate imageDiv and that means that textToBeOnTop must move as well. I also set a border.

So my problem is that I can see the border, but not the text.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: I should have put in original post, the image animates on hover through CSS, and I need to find a way to "ignore" the text to be on top as when the div is on top of the image, the hover for the image doesn't trigger

Thanks

Comment: Add relevant JS code...

Comment: @user3791979 Hi! :-) You may want to add the example code or a simple Jsfiddle so more people can get at you and help you quick/in a reasonable time. Thanks :-)

Comment: please take your time to review the answers and choose a correct one (or add your solution, if different).

Answer (score 1):

try this ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruk3U/))

```
<div class="imageDiv">
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/1/b/a/11971488211294199438barretr_Earth.svg.med.png">
    <div class="textToBeOnTop">Some text</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.imageDiv{
    position:relative;
}
.imageDiv .textToBeOnTop{
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following css code

```
.textToBeOnTop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Get for infor about position properties in html
http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you should elaborate on it a bit and explain what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

width of the class textToBeOnTop should be the same of img

```
   .textToBeOnTop{
     height:30px;
     width:auto;
    margin-top:-30px;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:8px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color:#000000;

    }
```

Comment: The problem is and I didn't explain in original post(I should have), is that the images animate on hover, and if the text to be on top is of the same size, the hover in the CSS doesn't trigger, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any JavaScript code, just CSS and HTML.

You can use the properties `position`, `z-index` and `margin` to achieve an over-impressed text, with something like this:

```
.myText {
    position: relative;
    margin: -100px 0 0 50px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.myImage {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Check out this working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GD56q/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
<div class="imagediv" style="height: 100px; width:100px; display:block;">
<img src="some-img.jpg" style="display:block;"/> /*display as block ,you can ommit this property *?
<span style="position:absolute;">Text over image</span> /*An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent */
</div>
```

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you should elaborate on it a bit and explain what your code does.

Comment: An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element(class imagediv)..so it always will be at top..

Comment: after giving absolute position,you can also set top  and left proerty to move element wherever you want

Comment: Instead of commenting on your answer you may want to edit it to add the additional info.

Answer (score 0):

In Css using Position relative and absolute you can put the text on top of the image.

For Example:

```
.image {
  position:relative;
}

.text_on_top {
postion:absolute;
top:0px;
left:10px;
}


<div class="image">
    <p class="text_on_top">Text for Image on the top</p>
<div>
```

Credit : [Display text on top of image](http://www.queryhome.com/50701/how-to-display-text-on-top-of-the-image)

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution: [Image with text aligned](http://jsfiddle.net/h9AVJ/)

**HTML**

---

```
<div class="imageDiv">
  <img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/3531bba.jpg">
  Some text
</div>
```

**css**

---

```
    .imageDiv{
    height:200px;
    width:240px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:200px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
    font-size:50px;
    color:white;
}

img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:-1;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

---

> Ask anytime if you have queries!

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use background-image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.bgDiv 
{
background-image:url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/1/b/a/11971488211294199438barretr_Earth.svg.med.png');
width:300px;
height:300px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class='bgDiv'>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SBcNG/)